Can't upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10 or 24.04
Can't upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10 or 24.04.
Background
I have a fancy workstation (I am the only user) that for some reason they let me have root but not bios/boot menu access because of over zealous security, and also because of over zealous security all new systems users are not allowed to use linux and user don't have an software installation rights. So upgrading from usb is a no go.I would rather keep my grandfathered in workstation and not have to move to Windows and ask permission every time I need to update a python package....
below are somethings I tried and their outputs
sudo do-release-upgrade

An upgrade from 'lunar' to 'noble' is not supported.

sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.

From some search it looks like I need to upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10 to 24.04. Is there a way to do that?
EDIT: I am not trying to skip a release, I am just looking for any method outside of a USB install to upgrade.

This question is similar to: Can I skip over releases when upgrading?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu 23.04 was an interim release in the two year development cycle of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (ie. 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 & 24.04 are all part of the same full two year cycle), so upgrades are supported from one release to the next, with 23.04 upgraded to 23.10.  That upgrade path ended when 23.10 reached EOL.  The upgrade instructions were found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades however https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/ shows its no longer available as https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release has Supported: 0

FYI:  Since you mention do-release-upgrade -d, that'll use https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development instead, where neither 23.04 or 23.10 are mentioned; thus -d won't help & ideally explain why you received the message you did (ie. it's intended for a 24.04 system to upgrade to Ubuntu oracular or what will be 24.10 on release; 24.10 being the first interim release in the development of 26.04)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades is the official doc on EOL Upgrades.   Note 3.10 is now EOL; so you need to skip that release as you cannot upgrade to an EOL release

Easiest fix is to fresh install.

This question is similar to: How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use the GRUB shell of your existing Ubuntu install to boot from USB: press Esc once or twice, then configfile (hd1,msdos1)/boot/grub/grub.cfg.  This is untested, I might've gotten the disk/partition number or the grub.cfg filename wrong, but you can use tab-completion and/or grub's ls command to discover the right ones.

I followed the directions here regarding Unsupported upgrades: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Sometimes do-release-upgrade isn't able to run the upgrade to the latest version and it shows an error similar to this:
An upgrade from 'eoan' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool.

If that happens, you need to download a version-specific upgrader, you can find the link at https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release.
You need to download the upgrade tool for the version you are upgrading to. For example, if you are upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 (focal), you'll see the link on that page as follows:
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz

The download is an archive which contains an executable with the code name of the release. execute it to run the upgrade tool for that release. Note that the archive extracts everything in the current directory so you might want to create a directory for it to extract into:
# Downloads the upgrader, check the link above for the URL of the file for your release
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/mantic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/mantic.tar.gz
# Extract it into a new directory
mkdir upgrader
tar -xaf mantic.tar.gz -C upgrader
cd upgrader
# Run the executable, the name changes based on the release
sudo ./mantic



Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Wow, there are like dozens of instances of this question and they all say it's impossible - yours saved the day.
Using your solution I did 23.04->23.10+reboot+23.10->24.04 - Amazing - thank you so much!

failed for me.
ntier@PrecisionM2800:~/upgrader$ sudo ./oracular
can't load DistUpgradeViewGtk3 (replace() argument 2 must be str, not None)
can't load DistUpgradeViewKDE (No module named 'PyQt4')
Reading cache
Checking package manager
Can not upgrade
An upgrade from 'lunar' to 'oracular' is not supported with this
tool.

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/mantic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/mantic.tar.gz leads to ERROR 404: Not Found now.

@user643722 Try changing archive.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com

@RichardEdwards Thanks, that worked; wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/mantic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/mantic.tar.gz.

Alas, with the mantic installer via old-releases.ubuntu.com, the instructions fail for me soon after sudo ./mantic with a Message Box titled "Error during update" including text such as "W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely..." and "E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file..." (and similar for mantic-updates and mantic-security).

Actually, it seems to be working now. I'd missed the step at the Ubuntu EOLUpgrades link, regarding the update of sources.list; I changed to using "old-releases" and all seems to be running well.
