Stuck in Ubuntu 23.04
I am an occasional Ubuntu user. My last version on my Dell XPS 13 laptop was 23.03 (Lunar). The PC was in storage for a long while. I pulled it out to update it, but neither the upgrade manager nor terminal commands will execute an upgrade to 24.04 (Noble).
All updates have been made. The message is the "an upgrade from lunar to noble is not supported on this tool".
Is there another tool?
I am NOT facile with Linux code.

23,04 is EOL. and we do not answer questions or problems about EOL,You can either use this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1520948/cant-upgrade-from-23-04-to-23-10-or-24-04 or actually more problem free backup your data, take your time, make a USB of Ubuntu 24.04.01, use Try Ubuntu and check everything, sound, video, etc. If everything works just install the new version instead.

btw 23.10 is also EOL.

Fresh install 24.04 (supported until 2029). It is the easiest way

Ubuntu 23.04 had a single fully supported upgrade path; which was to the next release being 23.10; that upgrade no longer existed once 23.10 reached EOL.  There is a two year development cycle for a LTS release with the interim releases of 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 being part of the 24.04 LTS cycle; using an interim release in that cycle required upgrade thru all (you can skip into the cycle, but not skip once inside). Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades which is where you are now.

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Even all EOL claims from "official" sources, you still can get some advice from https://kontext.tech/article/1380/upgrade-from-ubuntu-23-04-to-24-04 about how to go from "lunar" to "mantic" and from there you'll get rid of the error message from the "tool".
