404 error while upgrading from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 to 24.04
I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 23.04, however I get the following error.
An upgrade from 'lunar' to 'noble' is not supported with this tool.
After some online searching, I came across this instruction
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades, and I was trying to follow it. In the first step, I tried to find out if my version was EOL.
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 23.04"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="23.04"
VERSION="23.04 (Lunar Lobster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=lunar
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=lunar
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

I tried checking if my version is EOL by going to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases.
 But in that webpage version 23.04 is not listed. How can we find if a particular version is EOL or not if that version number is not listed on this page?
In this, it is listed that Ubuntu 23.04 lunas is EOL, so as per the instruction I'm trying to update to 23.10 and then to 24.04. For this, I created a sources.list file as below
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar-backports main restricted universe multiverse

However, when I do $ sudo apt update I get the following error,
Ign:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease     
Ign:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Err:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.37 80]
Err:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.37 80]
Err:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.37 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Why is this error coming? How can I update to 23.10 ? I can not do a fresh installation for practical reasons.
Edit: My question is NOT if I can skip versions while upgrading, my question is HOW to reach version 24.04 from 23.04. I don't mind doing intermediate steps. The suggested question does not have an accepted answer and none of the questions answer how to upgrade from 23.04 lunar.

Ubuntu 23.04's upgrade path was to the next release (23.10) as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades/ however that upgrade path closed with 23.10 reached EOL.  Ubuntu 23.10 could release-upgrade to 24.04; so 23.04 users to release-upgrade to 23.10 before it reached EOL then move to 24.04 after it had released.

This question is similar to: Can I skip over releases when upgrading?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@guiverc I have modified the question. My intention is to upgrade from 23.04 to 24.04, I don't mind the intermediate step. I can't even update to 23.10.

The intermediate step closed when 23.10 reached EOL, and the upgrade process from 23.04 to 24.04 requires you to go thru that intermediate step, as the two year development cycle for 24.04 included 22.10, 23.04, 23.04 before final 24.04; and upgrades must be thru that process OR from a prior cycle (ie. 22.04 -> 24.04 is supported; as is 23.10 -> 24.04).  The dup link I provided explains why; you've missed the supported path so re-install is expected; otherwise the somewhat manual EOLUpgrades process (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

You can refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1520948/cant-upgrade-from-23-04-to-23-10-or-24-04 for someone's understanding of it & how it worked (*do note you'll need to adjust answer a little I suspect; the answer was written (I suspect at quick glance) by someone describing a different upgrade; but its still the process mentioned in the EOLUpgrades link already provided)...  If you want an easy path, do it within the six months of EOL after which you're trying to skip releases.

You'll also need to adjust to match where the state is... eg. a quick look at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ and the MOVE hasn't yet happened (notices said in coming weeks; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/ but its still not done) which means that 'move' needn't be taken into account yet for mantic step.  As 23.10 is EOL; upgrades to it are no longer supported... so adjust manually if you see problems... (eg. old-releases had errors; quick open with browser, then switch to main archive as I shows state)..

404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.37 80] may be due to an error from the website, see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1530272/issues-with-apt-update-unable-to-reach-http-archive-ubuntu-com You may retry again.

Is this explained at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades ?

23.04 is indeed listed on the linked wiki page.

Ubuntu 23.04 reached End of Life on January 25, 2024.
