Issues with apt update - Unable to Reach http://archive.ubuntu.com/
I've recently started experiencing problems with running the apt update command on my system. It seems that the URL http://archive.ubuntu.com/ is currently unreachable, and as a result, the update process fails. I've tried multiple times, but the issue persists.
Is anyone else facing the same issue or know of any workarounds? Could this be a temporary issue with the repository, or do I need to change some settings?
I'm running Ubuntu 22.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Same problems with http://security.ubuntu.com

Could you please update your question with the full output of the 'sudo apt update' command ? And also of 'lsb_release -a', thanx.

I am using "http://archive.ubuntu.com/" as remote url for Nexus proxy:
Here is shorten output of apt update command:
404  Remote Auto Blocked until 2024-10-17T09:19:51.366+02:00 [IP: XXX80]
Fetched 279 kB in 1s (187 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch
http://NexusIP/repository/apt-jammy-proposed-proxy/dists/jammy-proposed/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Remote Auto Blocked until 2024-10-17T09:19:51.366+02:00 [IP: NexusIP 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

The page http://archive.ubuntu.com/ is slow and sometimes unreachable, so I think they might have some problems with disk on their system.

I think the problem is fixed now. In my case "apt update" command works fine and http://archive.ubuntu.com/ is browsable.
The problem was solved on remote server.
This question/problem can be closed.
